# Null space of A

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I feel heavily confident on getting part a, but not so confident with part b. Did I do that correctly or is there a part I completely missed or did I just mess up on everything for part b?

A = \begin{matrix}
    2 & 0 & 0 \\
    2 & 2 & 1 \\
    3 & 6 & 3 \\
   \end{matrix}

a) Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Eigenvalues= 0,2,5

Eigenvector 1=[0, -1/2, 1], Eigenvector 2= [-6, 1, 12], and Eigenvector 3= [0, 1 ,3]

b)Describe the null space of A and relate it to part A.

For part B I rref(A) to get 
\begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1/2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{matrix}

x_1=0 , x_2= -1/2x_3 , and x_3= x_3 to get a null space of 
 \begin{matrix}
    0 \\
    -1/2 \\
     1\\ 
   \end{matrix}

For the relation to A, it's the same as getting the eigenvector using the eigenvalue 0.

Comment: For eigenvector 1, you're missing a negative sign.  The eigenvector for 2 should just be $[1,0,0]$.  The third one is correct.

Comment: The eigenvector (2) which I used the eigenvalue of 2 I get [-1/2z, 1/12z, z] and I just made z=12 so there were no fractions. I'm not exactly sure how its what you put. But thank you for the correction and the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $b$ notice that since Det$(A) = 0$ we know that $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue.

But we know also that seeking for the null space of $A$ will give us exactly the eigenvector related to the eigenvalue $0$.

Since exists a $2\times 2$ minor invertibile (for example the principal one), we know that the rank of $A$ is $2$, so the dimension of the null space of $A$ is $1$ by the dimension formula.

So there unless scalar we know that $span(v) = Ker(A)$. To find such $v$ we just need to find one, since the other will be $\mu v, \mu \in \mathbb{K}$.

From the matrix $A$ we notice that if we call $C_{i}$ the $i$-th column $C_{2} = 2C_{3}$ which tell us that denoted by $e_{1},e_{2},e_{3}$ the canonical base $$A(e_{2}-2e_{3}) = A(e_{2})-2A(e_{3}) = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 2 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} - 2 \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Hence, $e_{2}-2e_{3} \in Ker(A)$ but since $\mbox{dim}(span(e_{2}-2e_{3})) = 1 = \mbox{dim}(Ker(A))$ we conclude that $span(e_{2}-2e_{3}) = Ker(A)$

Comment: I get that but are you saying that the null space I have is correct or incorrect?

Comment: $e_{2}-2e_{3} = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix} = - 2\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ -\frac{1}{2} \\ 1\end{pmatrix} $, which means they span the same subspace, hence $Ker(A)$, so your null space is correct

Comment: Oh okay fully get it now thank you! That clicked everything together.